# To describe the spider-man shooting a web, should it be "hand" or "hands"?

Tags: grammar

A [post](https://marvelanimated.fandom.com/wiki/Episode:Night_of_the_Lizard) describe the screenshot below as "He extends his **hands** and shoots out a web and swings through the skyscrapers, rounding a building."

[image]

Which comes from
https://youtu.be/4ERz_mwD1rI?list=PLkO_LIOUxjY-xJ0MV-UbVZ2fTyN2hRf83&t=4

The camera shot doesn't show the other hand of the spider-man.

Should it be "hand" or "hands" there?

Comment: If he uses both hands, it does not matter that we are only shown one in that shot.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you. He doesn't use both hands at the same time. He extends one hand, shoots and swings and then extends the other hand, shoots and swings, right?

Comment: You probably walk by extending one leg at a time. So do you walk with your leg, or walk with your legs? ;)

Comment: We can describe an instance of your walking process by saying “S/he moves her right leg forward, and brings it down to the ground, narrowly missing smashing an ant crawling across the trail. The sun beats down. S/he continues up the mountain.” Or “S/he keeps moving her legs forward, though s/he’s so tired she almost passes out. S/he continues walking until she reaches the city.” 

These are both perfectly natural and grammatical choices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentence as used in the post is fine.

It is not used to “describe the screenshot,” but to narrate the story using the “dramatic present.”

Either choice would be fine. If we use “hand”, we describe a more precise moment, like a snapshot of the singular action.

If we use “hands” we are describing the process he uses to move over a series of web shoots.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present